# What is interpolation in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to make word cloud using wordcloud library, while plotting it using `imshow`, there is an `interpolation` argument. There are different options like `"bilinear"`, `"bicubic"`, `"antialiased"`, etc, which can be chosen.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.imshow(wordcloud,interploation=None)
plt.show()
```

I want to know exactly what is interpolation and how it works for different values. I tried looking at the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html), but I do not understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpolation refers to the method used to estimate the values of pixels in a new image that is generated from an original image. The interpolation parameter determines how the image is displayed or rendered on the screen.

Interpolation methods aim to smooth or interpolate pixel values when displaying the image at a size different from its original resolution. These methods are necessary because resizing or displaying an image at a different scale often requires generating additional pixels to fill the gaps between the existing pixels.

'nearest': This method displays each pixel as a single color, without any smoothing or interpolation. It is the fastest but can result in a pixelated appearance.

'bilinear': Bilinear interpolation computes the new pixel value as a weighted average of the nearest four pixels in the original image. It provides smoother results compared to 'nearest' but may still show some blurriness.

'bicubic': Bicubic interpolation is a more advanced method that uses a weighted average of 16 neighboring pixels to compute the new pixel value. It offers better image quality than bilinear interpolation but requires more computational resources.

'antialiased': This option applies antialiasing techniques to smooth the edges of displayed lines and shapes, resulting in a higher-quality image. It is particularly useful when displaying images with sharp edges or text.

Comment: Link-only answers are not enough on Stack Overflow, as per: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259

Comment: That is especially true when the question includes the link you provided and says that it didn't help.

Comment: Thanks @jared for letting me know. I was unaware.